# Change a shortcut on keyboard plugged in in OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Friends,

I have two USB keyboards and I want to have different combinations of the following shortcut with different keyboards.

Is there a way that I could automate that change on keyboard being plugged in/out?

[image]

Comment: So you want different shortcuts when using different keyboards?

Comment: @Burgi Yes, that's what I want.